Provide 5V and 5A through USB-C
I need to power a Raspberry Pi 4 using an ATX power supply. Unfortunately, it needs to be done this way for reasons beyond my control.
My solution was to connect a +5V and a ground wire of the power supply with a USB-C breakout board (https://soldered.com/product/usb-c-female-connector-breakout/).
I'm doing so much digging and I don't really know how to proceed with CC1 and CC2 now or if I could just leave it the way it is since the ATX power supply will deliver as much as the Raspberry needs.
I have a 100W USB-C cable that probably has the E-Tag chip, but I really don't know too much about it and I'm a little too stupid to understand most of the documentation myself.
I hope I have provided enough information.
Thank you very much.
Max

Why can't you power it from the GPIO connector? Type-C will work as well - The Pi should work with Type-A to Type-C cable. So you could chop up a Type-A to Type-C cable and feed 5V through it. Or is there something I don't follow what you are asking and why - does the Pi use the CC pin for something? Also, by specification, you are not allowed to use your female connector for supplying 5V without proper handshaking, so you can't just connect 5V to breakout board VBUS. USB forbids it.

Well, since I have to obey the security rules, I can't just use the GPIO port, because that would disable a security feature of the Raspberry. This would mean that I would have to redo the whole safety check for everything.
There are a lot of people who use a female type-C breakout board for power, so I thought I could do that as well, but since the Raspberry wants 5 amps, it seems like quite a hassle.
I'm not sure about the CC pin on the Raspberry Pi 4.
Do you have any idea where I could find a solution?

The Pi 4 should be a 3A device. Can it even communicate with a supply to provide 5A? Also, do you have 12V available from the ATX supply? Or are you using 5V standby?

I'm using the 12V from the ATX for something else, but I could always tap into it.
I got the 5Amps from the official powersupply and just guessd it needs that, so even if it communicates I should be good with just putting 2 10K resistors on CC1 and CC2 and tell the raspberry I can provide 3 Amps?

Why are you looking at the supply specs instead of Rpi specs? If Rpi is an official device intended to work with official devices, it is not allowed to pull more than what is advertized to it, and in no case it is allowed to draw 5A without USB-PD communication, and the supply is likely not allowed to provide 5A. Unless you are using non-compliant devices anyway.

Well I did it because I´m not to good with electronics and just thought the Offical Rasperry powerblock will provide what the Raspberry Pi 4 needs. I wasn´t aware that there is a difference until you said that it takes only 3 Amps.

If the Rpi needs more than 3A then it can't work with standard USB-C devices and is non-compliant. If so, maybe that's why it requires an "official Pi supply"?

I can't really prove it but it looks as if the Raspberry Pi 4 has not been designed for 3A of current. Likely the USB-C connector and the PCB traces are too weak. You seem to have safety requirements. So it's not an option. Also see https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/develop/documentation/asciidoc/computers/raspberry-pi/power-supplies.adoc

Can you attach (solder) a Type-C cable to your ATX power supply permanently, making it as "power supply with captive Type-C cable"?

@Codo, per your own github link, the Paspberry Pi 4 is designed for 3A. However, all these power restrictions do depend on the number and quality of plugged-in USB peripherals, so this 3A number is poorly specified. And the 5A number is needed for Raspberry 5, not 4, OP should make a note.

@Ale..chenski You are correct. I meant to say that I doubt the Raspberry Pi 4 is designed for 5A as asked for by the OP. But the linked page does not explicitly specify how much current it can carry from the power input to connected shields and peripherals.


I need to power a Raspberry Pi 4 using an ATX power supply.

I think the problem is blown out of proportion. If you have to use ATX power supply, it is your proprietary solution. Unfortunately, you cannot use standard C-C cables to power a 5A Raspberry Pi 5, but a 3-A Pi4 should be no problem.
Instead of making a non-standard Type-C receptacle connected to ATX PSU, you just need to modify a standard TYPE-C cable: cut one end and solder GND and VBUS wires to a standard 4-pin Molex connector. And pull CC wire to +5V with 10k resistor (I believe the RPi4 needs this signal on their 5.1k pull downs, but it is not for sure). This arrangement will make your assembly as a standard USB charger with captive cable.
Per USB Type-C specifications Rev.2.2, chargers with captive cables are allowed to have VBUS asserted without sensing an external device connection (although it is recommended), see section 4.8.1.2 USB-based Chargers with USB Type-C Captive Cables, USB Type-C® Cable and  Connector Specification, October 2022
To be fair, this allowance has been removed from later specifications.
Since RPi5 is non compliant to USB anyway (there is no 27W power profile in PD at 5V, only 25W), everything should be okay, or, at least, "who cares".

Sounds like you are trying to do non-compliant USB things.
As fas as I know, RPi4 cannot communicate via USB Power Delivery messages, so it cannot request or draw 5A to begin with, as it cannot know if you have a 5A (100W) cable or standard 3A cable, or direct connection to a power supply with a non-detachable cable that can support 3A or 5A.
Also USB Power Delivery does not allow more than 3A at 5V so you can't even negotiate it.
So officially, it must be a 3A device or it is non-compliant.
If you want to build a cable for it, yes you need to have 10k pull-ups on cable CC wires to 5V.
But officially, you cannot do that through an Type-C receptacle having 5V always present. Unofficially you can do it. Officially only a Type-C plug can have always 5V present like on a Type-A to Type-C cable, but not the receptacle, as if you do so, it allows you to accidentally plug two of your ATX supplies together with a standard C-to-C cable if you had two.
So, I guess what I am trying to say is that 3A should be enough, as long as you don't put loads on the Raspberry Pi that make it go above 3A. Regarding "security", please remember that it is a hobbyist toy, and even the early RPi4 had implemented the Type-C interface incorretly and did not work if you had standard compliant supply and E-Mark cable as the CC pins were connected incorrectly. So it's good enough for a non-official prototype, but do consider if you trust it enough to make it a part of an official product. If it is inside your own product it should not matter if you power it from the GPIO headers or not.
One final thought, use a standard Type-C car adapter for any amps you want and power it from ATX supply 12V lines.

USB PD does allow for more than 3A at 5V. The Raspberry Pi 5 makes use of it. But it's such an unusual corner of the specification, that only very very few power supplies support it. The Raspberry Pi 27W supply is such an exception.

@Codo I need to investigate that - is that allowed on PD3 or PD2? But Pi4  doesn't talk PD anyway.

As far as I understand, it's already part of PD2. For the Pi4, it's irrelevant indeed.

Thank both of you very much this was very helpful. The Idea with the car adapter is very smart as a last resort option. I'll first try to use my breakout board next week and see what happens. If that fails I'll go with that option and make it work.

Sounds like it is not the OP, but the Raspberry Pi is not compliant to USB. Raspberry Pi is known for long time for not observing USB power framework, https://superuser.com/a/1123119/620011

In a USB-C port or as shown in the breakout connector board's circuit diagram, the CC1 and CC2 pins are the Channel Configuration pins. They perform a number of functions such as

cable attachment and removal detection,
receptacle/plug orientation detection, and
current advertisement.

These pins could be also used for the communications required by the Power Delivery and Alternate Mode.
Here is a link to a very informative article about it. Hope it helps.

Everything you say is correct but does not answer the question.

Thank you very much. I have already read this page, although I will not say that I understood everything, it seems that there is now an answer or explanation to my problem.
